# Error 404 in local host Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have error 404 while running localhost:8080 in Spring Boot

Error

```
 Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Sep 27 14:44:36 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEsdM.png)

My Controller class

```
package chi.student.controller;


import chi.student.model.Student;
import chi.student.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "studentRepository")
    public void setStudentRepository(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listStudents(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        model.addAttribute("listStudents", this.studentRepository.findAll());
        return "students";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/students/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
        if (student.getId() == 0) {
            this.studentRepository.save(student);
        } else {
            this.studentRepository.save(student);
        }
        return "redirect:/students";
              }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeStudent(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.studentRepository.delete((long) id);
        return "redirect: /students";
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String editStudent(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", this.studentRepository.findOne((long) id));
        model.addAttribute("listStudents", this.studentRepository.findAll());
        return "students";

    }

    @RequestMapping("studentdata/{id}")
    public String studentData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", this.studentRepository.findOne((long) id));
        return "studentdata";

    }


    }
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-digester3', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.1'



}
```

What I'm doing wrong? It can't find my index.jsp and other pages

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>StudentBook</title>
</head>
<body background="http://s1.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2012/10/9b5f28f249b60412a4cf9cbc7cf8af4b.jpg">
<h1 align="center">Welcome!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Where should I provide my index.jsp to make Controller see it?

Comment: what url are you trying to access ?

Comment: Well above, the url you try to access doesn't exist....

Comment: I'll try to access localhost:8080/index

Comment: In the controller you put, It doesn't exist. I recommend you `spring-boot-actuator`, put it in your pom and go to `localhost:8080/mappings`: you can  see all your mappings, and be sure if /index exist or not. In your case I'm sure there isn't a index mapping

Comment: it asks user and password when I'm trying to get "localhost:8080/mappings" , but I've disabled spring security from my spring-boot

Comment: It doesn't seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the view to you're mappings.

There are two differents ways to do it.

#### 1) Configuring WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
     }
}
```

#### 2) Returning the view in a request mapping of a controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    ....
    @RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listStudents(Model model) {
        //your impl if is need
        return "index"; //or the view you want
    }
}
```

As @wilsoncampusaon says the path were your views should be is  `/src/main/resources/templates/`.

Comment: How you second way differs from my controller? I couldn't understand

Comment: I have 2 pages except index.jsp(studentdata and students) I need to add view controllers to each pages?

Comment: Sorry for dummy question, but should I use .html or .jsp is OK?

Comment: It depends on your needs, both are valids.

Answer (score 0):

By default the viewresolver on spring boot will look for the views in /src/main/resources/templates/ .

I can't see your structure right now but try to move your html views to that folder.

Comment: Thanks @pauchorro, I can't see the structure he has... but he remarks he cannot find his pages. what do you think ?

Comment: I think he forget to create a mapping returing the view or add view controller